# UITableViewCells invalid context trying to draw

Tags: ios, uitableview, cgcontext

I am trying to draw a checkbox triangle in a UITableViewCell.
In the Data Source protocol method -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: I have added the following in the code bloc which asks if the cell is nil:

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 75,10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 10, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 160, 150);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

When executing the code, I get a series of 'invalid context 0x0' messages on the following methods:
CGContextBeginPath:
CGContextMoveToPoint:
CGContextAddLineToPoint: (twice)
CGContextClosePath:
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor:
CGContextDrawPath

The messages repeat for each TableViewCell row in my table.

Am I not able to draw triangles or other geometric shapes within customizedUITableViewCell objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will not return a valid context if called outside `drawRect:`. You have to do your custom drawing in a view's `drawRect:` method. For your purpose, you should probably create a custom `UIView` subclass for your checkbox and add that view as a subview to the cell.