# Add view onto UIViewController

Tags: xcode, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have made a UIImagePicker

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

And I want to add a half circle to to so I do this,

```
CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(gc);
    CGContextAddArc(gc, 100, 100, 50, -M_PI_2, M_PI_2, 1);
    CGContextClosePath(gc); // could be omitted
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(gc, [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(gc);
    UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    [someView.layer renderInContext:gc];
    [picker setCameraOverlayView:someView];
```

But then when I show the picker like so

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I don't see the semicircle? Why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are not going on proper way.

Do the below step it will help you...

See the below answer..
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552210/uitableviewcells-invalid-context-trying-to-draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932654/invalid-context-0x0-error-when-using-cgcontext-functions)

**CircleView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CircleView : UIView

@end
```

**CircleView.m**

```
#import "CircleView.h"

@implementation CircleView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
  {
    CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(gc);
    CGContextAddArc(gc, 100, 100, 50, -M_PI_2, M_PI_2, 1);
    CGContextClosePath(gc); // could be omitted
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(gc, [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(gc);
 }
 @end
```

**Implimenttion of adding half circle in your imagepicker is here**

```
 UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController   alloc]init];
 controller.delegate=self;
 controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
            CircleView *someView = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
            [someView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5]];
            [controller setCameraOverlayView:someView];
        }];
```

Comment: okay thanks, Im just a little confused about what the DrawCircleView is?

Comment: Hey i add the code for h file and m file.. just make it ,,